# How to change font in Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0 in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, help-viewer

I installed Visual Studio 2012 and noticed that the help viewer uses different font from that in Visual Studio 2008. Is there any way to change the font used in Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783335/help-viewer-2-0-ugly-monospace-font and https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729858/help-viewer-2-0-beta-allow-consolas-to-be-used-as-the-default-font-in-code-section

Comment: Thanks @Cody. Actually what I meant is not the font specifically used in the code section, but in the main section. I would prefer to see the same font used in VS2008 help viewer.

Comment: Well, either way, I suspect it isn't fixable. Otherwise there would be some indication of a workaround in those bug reports. Maybe someone else knows something I don't, though.